# Way to automatically click button that contains certain text?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, autofill, userscripts, tampermonkey

I've been searching restlessly for a way to automatically select a survey form button that contains a specific word. I am using Tampermonkey in Google Chrome. In this case, I would like to automatically select buttons with the word 'Male' in them.

Here is an example of the type of button I am talking about (including CSS/HTML):

[image]

So for the question: "What is your gender?", I would like to automatically select 'Male.' I have been running through all of the stackoverflow questions I can find that could possibly help, but with no results. I chose a label-based method and used "textContent" to hopefully be able to recognize the text within the form question.

Here is the code I am currently working with (from [How can I auto-select a radio button with Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169595/how-can-i-auto-select-a-radio-button-with-greasemonkey)):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Button Text Form Filler
// @include      https://tasupport.co1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_0qez6NHJGoCAmMt
// @version      1.0
// @description  Demonstration script to change form values
// ==/UserScript==

var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label'); 
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i) { 
    if (labels[i].textContent == "Male") { 
        labels[i].click(); 
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the code doesn't work and the button for 'Male' is not selected on page load. This can be tested in the 2nd page of the following website: https://tasupport.co1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_0qez6NHJGoCAmMt (where the above screenshot comes from).

I have also tried the following with jQuery ([How do I automatically click this button with tampermonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444367/how-do-i-automatically-click-this-button-with-tampermonkey)):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         jQuery Button Test
// @version      0.1
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
// @include      https://tasupport.co1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_0qez6NHJGoCAmMt
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button:contains('Male')").click();
});
```

Again, nothing.

There are a few similar questions to mine scattered across stackoverflow, but none of the solutions appear to work here, or perhaps the code I am working with is outdated. I would appreciate any and all help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following in the dev console and it works.
Hope it helps

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('label > span')).find(e => e.textContent === 'Male').parentElement.click()
```

The label has an id you can use. You don't need to search in the textContent for Male when you use these id.

```js
document.getElementById('QID2-1-label').click()
```

---

**edit**

for tampermonkey you need some settings to deal with the xhr requests.
You need jQuery, waitForKeyElements.js and the @match needs your xhr urls.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You

// @match        https://tasupport.co1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_0qez6NHJGoCAmMt
// @match        https://tasupport.co1.qualtrics.com/jfe2/form/SV_0qez6NHJGoCAmMt/next?rand=775440350&tid=1&t=1547858208474
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

const fire = () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('label > span')).find(e => e.textContent === 'Male').parentElement.click();

// another option
// const fire = () => document.getElementById('QID2-1-label').click();

waitForKeyElements (
    "#QID2-1-label",
    fire
);
```

Comment: This works in the console on my end as well! Thank you. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to work on page load in Tampermonkey. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: I think it may be AJAX driven so I am trying to find solutions that deal with dynamic loading.

Comment: yes, you are right. The AJAX-Requests are the problem. I have edit my post. Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks again! Just wondering, is there a way to do this with the first jQuery code you posted? I would like to use the method of finding the actual string of text instead of using elementID if possible. I would like to apply this method to other webpages that might have different element IDs.

Comment: The first code works too. (not jQuery - normal JavaScript)

`const fire = () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('label > span')).find(e => e.textContent === 'Male').parentElement.click()`

Comment: Beautiful, this is amazingly helpful. One last question, say I want to apply this on a different page, but the labels are different. Is there another way to use "waitForKeyElements" that could be more generally applied?

Comment: If you know, that all sites have `<label>` elements, you can also use `label` for the waitForKeyElements. It`s not optimal but it would work. 

waitForKeyElements (
    "label",
    fire
);

Comment: That might just work! It worked when I tried it with Tampermonkey on my example page. You've helped so much, thanks again!

Comment: Oh, and say I want to include other words, like 'Mr.," for instance. How could I do this? I would need to modify find(e => e.textContent === 'Male'). Maybe find(e => e.textContent === 'Male', 'Mr.')? Or should I just add another line and replace 'Male"?

Answer (score 1):

Try if this works

```
$( ".SingleAnswer span" ).each(function( index ) {
       if($( this ).text().includes("Male")) {
           $( this ).click()
       }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it in the console but kept getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:26

Answer (score 1):

There is no button element. The element listening to the user click event is actually a hidden input:

```html
<li class="Selection reg">
  <!-- this input -->
  <input choiceid="1" aria-labelledby="QID2-1-label" class="radio QR-QID2-1 QWatchTimer" type="radio" name="QR~QID2" id="QR~QID2~1" value="1" data-runtime-checked="runtime.Selected">

  <!-- not these elements -->
  <label for="QR~QID2~1" class="q-radio q-checked" aria-hidden="true" data-runtime-class-q-checked="runtime.Choices.1.Selected"></label>  <span class="LabelWrapper"> 
  <label for="QR~QID2~1" id="QID2-1-label" class="SingleAnswer  q-checked" data-runtime-class-q-checked="runtime.Choices.1.Selected"><span>Male</span></label></span> <div class="clear"></div>
</li>
```

So you need to call the `click` method of the `input` element to trigger it. For example you could do:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i) { 
    if (labels[i].textContent == "Male") { 
        labels[i].parentElement.parentElement.firstElementChild.click()
    }
}
```